# ¿Antónimo de colapsar en el contexto de una web?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, informática, antónimos

¿Cómo sería el antónimo de colapsar?

Contexto:

Al hacer hacer click en el botón de una web, el menú se *colapsa* y enseña todas las opciones.

Si volvemos a hacer click, el menú se... ¿descolapsa?

Comment: También `desplegar` como en `menu desplegable`

Comment: Creo que *colapsar* no es la palabra adecuada, no parece que las definiciones encajen con la acción de plegar o recoger un menú. Yo diría que es un calco de *collapse* en inglés que sí significa *plegar*, entre otras cosas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

¿Qué tal **expandir** en su tercera acepción en lugar de colapsar? No como antónimo, sino como palabra más adecuada. Haciendo esa sustitución, **colapsar** es la palabra por la que preguntas.

Cuando haces click, el menú se **expande** y enseña sus opciones. Si volvemos a hacer click entonces es cuando se **colapsa**, se cierra.

Según el DRAE

[**expandir**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HHZUKjU)

> 1. tr. Dilatar algo o hacer que aumente de tamaño. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Difundir o propagar algo, como una noticia o una idea. U. t. c. prnl.
>
> **3. tr. Extender algo, o hacer que ocupe más espacio**. U. t. c. prnl.

[**colapsar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9jmZSUA)

> 1. tr. Producir colapso a alguien o en algo.
> 2. intr. Sufrir colapso o caer en él. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. intr. Dicho de una actividad: **Decrecer o disminuir** intensamente.

---

Como han indicado @DGaleano y @guifa en los comentarios, quizás el término más común sea **menú desplegable**, por lo tanto las mejores opciones para describir la funcionalidad de ese elemento sean **desplegar** y **plegar**.

[**desplegar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DNRlXZo)

> 1. tr. Desdoblar o extender lo que está plegado.

Comment: **Expandir** y **desplegar** son los términos que siempre uso. Por aquí hablamos de menú **desplegable** o **expandible** +1

Comment: Yo también suelo usar desplegar, aunque expandir me parece opción igualmente adecuada (y probablemente la uso de vez en cuando sin darme cuenta).  Aunque yo también en caso de usar desplegar también uso plegar para decir colapsar por simetría.